# Use an Array as a parameter in WHERE clause in PHP

Tags: php

I want to select all from my workloaddata Table, where the Sched_Days field  has at least one similar day. With Days selected by the USER(via checkbox). Which the values are stored in  $wwdays variable.

I've converted my $wwdays into an array by doing $daysIn = explode(',', $wwdays, -1);

Now, I'm using $daysIn as a parameter in my WHERE clause, but my query is returning a false result. Is there something wrong with my syntax?

```html
 /*
 $wwdays has this string value "Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Saturday,"
 
 I've used $daysIn = explode(',', $wwdays, -1); To get just the days
 
 And used print_r($daysIn); to check the details, I have this result
 
 Array ( [0] => Monday [1] => Tuesday [2] => Wednesday [3] => Saturday ) 
 
 So I assume that my $daysIn variable is an array with the days as its element.
 
 */
 
$daysIn = explode(',', $wwdays, -1);

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "smis"); 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM workloaddata
WHERE Sched_Days IN (".implode(',',$daysIn).")
 ";
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
{
// do things ..
}

// I'm having  mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\
```

Answer (score 0):

You must do something like bellow (take in attention on comments):

```
// Connect to DB
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "smis");

$daysIn = explode(',', $wwdays);

// Clear white-spaces and prevent sql injection
$daysIn = array_map(function($item) use ($connect) {
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, trim($item));
}, $daysIn);

// Remove empty items
$daysIn = array_filter($daysIn);

if (!empty($daysIn)) {
    // Wrap "" on condition values
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `workloaddata` WHERE `Sched_Days` IN ("'.implode('","',$daysIn).'") ';

    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
    {
        // do things ..
    }
}
```

But it is recommended to **use PDO** and **bind params** instead of putting directly into query.

Comment: Hi, it seems like the while() loop is not being executed. I've tried to echo test messages inside the loop and outside of it. I'm always having the message from outside the loop.


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
    {  
        echo"true Inside while loop executed";

    }
  echo "<br>While statement not executed!!";

Comment: Please try to output sql query before execution, to check is it correct or not: `var_dump($sql)`